# How is the block interval constrained in Ethereum 2.0

Tags: proof-of-stake, casper, block-interval

Sorry if i get any of the terminology wrong here, i'm no expert when it comes to PoS protocols.

How does Ethereum 2.0 control for blocktime, typically we have the idea of a function that can be tuned via difficulty, i.e. requiring that as blocktimes (timestamps provided by miners) converge the difficulty of a function should increased.

Do we have the same idea in Ethereum 2.0? is there any measures in place to reduce the amount of blocks that can be created in a time period (do block producers include timestamps in blocks) and can block creation be limited by this?